# Question about the floor function.

Tags: functions, ceiling-and-floor-functions, function-and-relation-composition

Does $f(\lfloor x \rfloor)=g(\lfloor x \rfloor)$ imply that $f(x)=g(x)$ ?

Comment: Absolutely not.  Why would it?  If you want an explicit counterexample, consider manipulating $\sin(x)$ via scaling and comparing it to a constant function.  If you want an even simpler counterexample which requires no scaling at all, try comparing $\lfloor x\rfloor$ to $x$ itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ then you will have $f(\lfloor x \rfloor)=g(\lfloor x \rfloor)$. But the functions $f$ and $g$ can behave completely different on $\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Z}$. For example,
$$
f(x) = \left \{ 
\begin{eqnarray*}
x & , \quad x \in \mathbb{Z} \\
\pi &, \quad \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Z}
\end{eqnarray*}
\right.
$$
and
$$
g(x) = \left \{ 
\begin{eqnarray*}
x & , \quad x \in \mathbb{Z} \\
\sqrt{2} &, \quad \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Z}
\end{eqnarray*}
\right.
$$
have the property that $f(\lfloor x \rfloor)=g(\lfloor x \rfloor)$ but are clearly different functions.